# malloc a char pointer member of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

How can I allocate memory for a char pointer member of a non pointer struct?
Let me explain:
Here is a small program:

```
typedef struct student {
    char *name;
} student;
void main()
{
    /* If I declare a normal struct */
    student Josef;
    /* This line doesn't work */  
    Josef->name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    /* But if I declare a pointer to struct student */
    student *PJosef;
    /* This line works */
    PJosef->name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
}
```

Could you tell me why?
And by the way, I saw in some tutorials, a line that allocates memory for that struct pointer like:
PJosef = malloc(sizeof(student->PJosef)); // (or should I write "struct" before student, even if I typedef-ed?)
Is this line necessary? The program works without it.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Use `Josef.name` to access a struct member in a non-pointer context.

Comment: Thank you guys. what about allocating memory for the struct, is it necessary?

Comment: `student *PJosef; PJosef->name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));` invokes undefined behavior because you haven't allocated space for `PJosef` yet. Any time you have a pointer, it must point to valid memory before you dereference it, or you invoke UB.

Comment: @noname delete Read at last a book on C for beginners. It will be helpful.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I've read "Teach yourself c"

Comment: Consider: `student josef[1]; josef->name = malloc(...)` and `student *josef; josef = malloc(...); josef->name = malloc(...);` and `student josef; josef.name = malloc(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `->` operator in:

```
student Josef;
Josef->name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

Will not work because `Josef` is not a pointer to a `struct`.

The `->` operator can only be used on pointers to type `struct`. Using the `->` operator like you have, is equivalent to doing something like this:

```
*(Josef).name
```

This is completely wrong.

Instead you should use the `.` operator:

```
student Josef;
Josef.name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

Note:

```
student *PJosef;
PJosef->name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

Will not work because `PJosef` is a uninitialized pointer and accessing it invokes undefined behaviour.

Instead you must first allocate memory for a `struct`:

```
student *PJosef = malloc(sizeof(struct student)); 

if (PJosef == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed");
    // error procedure
}

PJosef->name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: I now see that even if I tried to make this question understandable, I forgot that the struct name is Josef and it doesn't need a "name" member.

Answer (score 1):

The second example is invalid. As you do not allocate memory for the struct itself you dereference the dangling pointer and invoke a UB.

It should be

```
student *pJosef = malloc(sizeof(*pJosef));
if(pJosef)
   pJosef -> name = malloc(20 * sizeof(pJosef -> name[0])); // here also check if allocation failed. 
else { /* error handling */}
```

Note usage of the objects not types in `sizeof`s